# Multiple condition on same column in sql or in pyspark

Tags: mysql, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset below:

```
|acc_no|acc_type_id|bal_amt|bal_type_id|    curr_code|        forex|  
|   123|          1| 123.45|          1|          USD|          1.0|  
|   123|          1|  124.0|          2|          USD|          1.0|  
|   123|          1| 200.56|          3|          USD|          1.0|  
|   124|          2|34500.0|          1|          INR|        0.014|  
|   124|          2|42000.0|          3|          INR|        0.014|  
|   125|          1|  470.0|          2|          USD|          1.0|  
|   125|          1|  470.0|          3|          USD|          1.0|  
|   126|          1|    0.0|          1|          USD|          1.0|  
|   126|          2|  370.0|          3|          USD|          1.0|
```

I need to select rows where bal_type_id = 3 only when bal_amt > 0 for bal_type_id = 1.

**Output Dataset :**

```
|acc_no|acc_type_id|bal_amt|bal_type_id|    curr_code|        forex|  
|   124|          2|42000.0|          3|          INR|        0.014|  
|   123|          1| 200.56|          3|          USD|          1.0|
```

How can I do this?. Please help.

Comment: *where bal_type_id = 3 only when bal_amt > 0 for bal_type_id = 1* And how to define what row with `bal_type_id = 3` matches the row with `bal_type_id = 1`? What column(s) must be equal?

Comment: You can refer the output dataset for this

Comment: Please answer my question, not your question which you imagine for me... Now I see 3 different joining conditions which result in shown dataset (by `acc_no`, by `acc_type_id`, by `acc_no, acc_type_id`). Using wrong condition in your query (which gives the output look like correct) you will somewhen obtain incorrect output- when the unsuccessful relation occures.

Comment: if  bal_type_id = 3 for acc_no then for that acc_no  bal_type_id = 1 must be present with bal_amt > 0. Then only select the row with bal_type_id = 3 otherwise dont select. I hope this make clear to you.

Comment: I.e. only `acc_no` equality is a criteria? even when, for example, `acc_type_id` or `curr_code` differs, the rows matches nevertheless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when bal_type_id = 1 then bal_amt end) over (partition by acc_no) as bal_amt_1
      from t
     ) t
where bal_amt_1 > 0 and bal_type_id = 3;
```

Or, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.bal_type_id = 3 and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.acc_no = t.acc_no and
                    t2.bal_type_id = 1 and
                    t2.amt > 0
             );
```

Comment: df1 = data1.select('*').where(F.col('bal_type_id') == 3)
    df2 = data1.select('acc_no').where((F.col('bal_type_id') == 1) & (F.col('bal_amt') > 0))

    joinedDf = df1.join(df2, df1['acc_no'] == df2['acc_no'], 'leftsemi')                                      I have done this, What is more optimize?

Comment: @MohammadSunny . . . You would need to test on your data and your database.  The window function should have reasonable performance, but sometimes the `exists` might be faster.

Comment: Your query also joins internally dataset. But Thanks @Gordon Linoff. It solves my problem.